# Value Error - Error when checking target - LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

## About the dataset

The following Reuters dataset contains 11228 texts that correspond to news classified in 46 categories. The texts are encripted in the sense that each word correspond to an integer number. I specify that we want to work with 2000 words.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

num_words = 2000
(reuters_train_x, reuters_train_y), (reuters_test_x, reuters_test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.reuters.load_data(num_words=num_words)

n_labels = np.unique(reuters_train_y).shape[0]
print("labels: {}".format(n_labels))

# This is the first new
print(reuters_train_x[0])
```

## Implementing the LSTM

I need to implement a network with a single LSTM with 10 units. The input needs an embedding with 10 dimensions before entering the LSTM cell. Finally, a dense layer needs to be added to adjust the number of outputs with the number of categories.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Embedding
from from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

reuters_train_y = to_categorical(reuters_train_y, 46)
reuters_test_y = to_categorical(reuters_test_y, 46)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim = num_words, 10))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(46,activation='softmax'))
```

## Training

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(reuters_train_x,reuters_train_y,epochs=20,validation_data=(reuters_test_x,reuters_test_y))
```

The error message that I get is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (46,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to one-hot-encode your `y` labels.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

reuters_train_y = to_categorical(reuters_train_y, 46)

reuters_test_y = to_categorical(reuters_test_y, 46)
```

Another bug I see in the `fit` function, you are passing `validation_data=(reuters_test_x,reuters_train_y)` but it should be `validation_data=(reuters_test_x,reuters_test_y)`

Your x is a numpy array of lists with different lengths. You need to pad the sequences to get a fixed shape numpy array.

```
reuters_train_x = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    reuters_train_x, maxlen=50
)

reuters_test_x = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    reuters_test_x, maxlen=50
)
```

Comment: I have amended the code accordingly but I´m still getting an error during the training of the model. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Check the updated answer, you need to use some padding.